# Java/SWT displaying an 8bit grayscaling Image from a byte array

Tags: java, swt

I'm building a GUI with the Eclipse Window Builder Editor.
I've made a Composite with a Gridlayout and have put a Label in there.
Some method from another class generates a raw 8 bit 1280x1024 grayscale image which is saved in a byte array.
This is how I generate my ImageData, etc in the mainMethod :

```
Color white = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE);
Color black = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK);

PaletteData palette = new PaletteData( 255, 255, 255 );

imgData = new ImageData(1280, 1024, 8, palette);

imgLabel = new Label(composite_3, SWT.NONE);
imgLabel.setImage(null);
imgLabel.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
```

I'm still having problems to understand what exactly I should do with the PaletteData as I don't need colours anyway. 
(Color)Depth should be 8 because I want it to have 255 grayvalues?

And this is my setImg method which gets called from another Thread as soon as the byte[] is filled with data:

```
public static void setImg(final byte[] b) {
    Display.getDefault().syncExec( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imgData.setPixels(0, 0, 1280, b, 0);
            img = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), imgData);
            Image grayImg = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), img, SWT.IMAGE_GRAY);
            imgLabel.setImage(img);

//              img.dispose();
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried

```
imgLabel.setImage(img);
```

and

```
imgLabel.setImage(grayImg);
```

Ok the first line now displays correctly...
It seems that I only can set 1 line of pixels with imgData.setPixels(...) which is kind of useless imo or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PaletteData` uses the constructor for a *direct* palette. I guess that what You want is the constructor for an indexed palette. See also [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-images/graphics-resources.html#PaletteData) and [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/graphics/PaletteData.html) for more explanation.

The following code snippet shows

- how to create a grey scale palette using an indexed palette
- how to set the image as a whole (not line by line)

  ```
  // pixel depth will be 8-bit, so there is space for 256 different (grey) values
  RGB[] rgb = new RGB[256];

  // build grey scale palette: 256 different grey values are generated. 
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      rgb[i] = new RGB(i, i, i);
  }

  // Construct a new indexed palette given an array of RGB values.
  PaletteData paletteData = new PaletteData(rgb);

  // create an image with given dimensions, depth and color palette
  ImageData imageData = new ImageData(1280, 1024, 8, paletteData);

  // data represents the pixels of the image. This corresponds to 'b' in Your code
  imageData.data = b;

  // note that there are also other 'Image', e.g. java.awt.Image
  org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), imageData);

  // paint
  imgLabel.setImage(img);

  // release operating system resources corresponding to the image
  image.dispose();
  ```

**NOTE:** I tried an example with Your PaletteData, e.g.

```
    PaletteData palette = new PaletteData( 255, 255, 255 );
```

and it worked in the sense that it showed some grey scale pictures (a video actually). However, the *indexed* version used in given code snippet was much more eye friendly. Have a look at the first link provided above. It gives a good explanation of the difference between *indexed* and *direct* color palette.